# posting reply to inbox message?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to post a reply to an inbox message by sending a POST request to `/message_id/comments`. Is this the correct way to send a reply to an inbox message ?

I'm getting the following error:

```
   "error": {
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "message": "(#3) App must be on whitelist"
   }
```

The token has every possible permission.

Do I have to ask that my app is added on a whitelist ? how to do so ?

I'm doing this in javascript+jQuery:

```
var params = {
    access_token: token
    , method: 'post'
    , message: 'hi'
};
$.getJSON('https://graph.facebook.com/$message_id/comments?callback=?', params, function(json) {

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Facebook apps by default aren't allowed to send messages on behalf of users.  There is no permission you are missing.  This is an extra level to prevent spam (beyond prompting the user who).  You will have to contact Facebook to get your application whitelisted.  I would try their [developer group](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/).

Answer (score 0):

opened a support ticket right here:
http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/183144141763793?browse=search_4e8b140cbf26e6040457329

Tried all I can think of and googled for, still getting this issue

Answer (score 0):

Like others have pointed out, there isn't a way to do this programmatically unless you are on Facebook's whitelist.  However, I did find a way around this for my app.  What I do is use Oauth to display messages from a user's FB inbox like normal.  When the user clicks 'Reply' on a message, I just send them to the reply page on Facebook Mobile, like this:

```
$('.reply').click(function() {
  var popup_window = window.open('http://touch.facebook.com/messages/compose?ids='+message_id, '_blank');
  popup_window.focus();
});
```

Where message id is the Facebook id for the message they are replying to.  In my case, I use PHP to echo the message id into a javascript variable or data-attribute when the page loads.  Since the Facebook mobile page opens in a new tab, they don't even really leave my app.  Since Facebook mobile has a very streamlined interface it isn't too distracting.  It's not perfect, but it works and it's easier than trying to get whitelisted.