# (#3) User must be on whitelist, music.listens - Open Graph Music

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i'v set up my Music Application using [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/music/).

i'm trying to pubish new user action but it wont work i'm getting (#3) User must be on whitelist.

this is the code.

```
        FB.api('/me/music.listens&song=track-page-url, 'post', function(response) {
            if(!response || response.error) {
                console.log(response.error);
            } else {
                console.log('success');
            }
        });
```

i googled the error and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7437051/3-app-must-be-on-whitelist-facebook) but it appears that there is no answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To apply to be whitelisted, follow the instructions in the Open Graph [Builtin Actions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/#listen) docs. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting "An unknown error has occurred.". It seems that music.listens only works for a certain set of applications such as MOG, Rdio, Spotify, Slacker Radio, etc.

Comment: then how do u explain the documentation, its available to any one.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook only allows whitelisted partners to take advantage of the Open Graph Music, on Facebook [Open Graph Music](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/music/), the first line:

> Facebook Open Graph Music is only available to whitelisted partners at
>   this time.