# Asking about Facebook Open Graph built-in action "games.win", "games.plays", "games.passes" and object "games.match"

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, facebook-apps

I've been doing research these few days, regarding built-in OpenGraph action and object for Facebook games. I noticed certain things.

- When we accessed our Application page with game category, Facebook will automatically put "you played [app name] in your activity list
- Some games can have playing instead of played.
- And some games can post an OpenGraph action with type of "games.win" and also object with type of "games.match"
- In Graph API Explorer, if you key in `/me/games.plays`, `/me/games.plays`, `/me/games.passes` you will notice these built in actions and object existence

Then in my research, below is the step that i've taken.

First i played a game "SongPop" until the app creates the games.win action and games.match object.

Then i take the activity or opengraph ID and then try to debug it with Facebook Debugger.
There i realizes the existence of this action and object.

Then i decided to create my own "games.match" object that can be debugged properly with Facebook Object debugger. (Sample taken from SongPop match, where the report is you beats someone)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# #######: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/#######">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="#######">
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="343622035704062" />
    <meta property="og:url"    content="http://#######/facebook/opengraph/gamematch/match_1.html">
    <meta property="og:title" content="90's Alternative Challenge">
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://ccmq-samples.s3.amazonaws.com/songpop/images/facebook/opengraph/90sAlternative.png">
    <meta property="og:description" content="Who is the best at guessing 90's Alternative songs?">
    <meta property="og:type" content="games.match">
    <meta property="games:players" content="facebook-userid">
    <meta property="games:players" content="facebook-userid">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I also Just realizes that in order to make this OpenGraph object works, you must have "gamematch" keyword in the URL.

Then i try to recreate the action with Graph API Explorer using POST method
The URL is `/me/games.win` and the parameter is `{"match": "url to the open graph object"}`

And then Graph API Explorer return this result

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#3) App must be on whitelist", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 3
  }
}
```

If i take SongPop user access token (got the token in the app page on chrome), the operation succeed and the said action will be recreated.

So there are few question that i wanted to ask.

1. Is there any written documentation of knowledge base regarding this games.win action, games.match object.
2. The (#3) App must be on whitelist error, do anyone know how to whitelist our application, or is it the app will be marked in whitelist after the OpenGraph action submission and review (haven't got into the process yet)

I've been assigned on development of such game which requires this OpenGraph actions. I've been looking on Facebook site, blog and stackoverflow.com without any clue.

Please advice.

Comment: Related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535583/3-user-must-be-on-whitelist-music-listens-open-graph-music