# How to get Facebook Group Albums via Open Graph

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=195466193802264%2Falbums

When I hit that link I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#3) App must be on whitelist", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 3
  }
}
```

Anyone know how to apply for access to this API?

Comment: Related post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7535583/3-user-must-be-on-whitelist-music-listens-open-graph-music

Answer (score 0):

It means specifically what it says the application must be approved and on Facebook's whitelist. The majority of applications are not whitelisted.

So a possible to accomplish this would be to become a Facebook Trusted Partner.

http://developers.facebook.com/preferredmarketingdevelopers/