# how to retrieve albums of a group in facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

How can I get albums list and its images from a group created in facebook using fql ?
what should I do ? Normal query not working..

```
SELECT  name,description,aid,object_id  FROM album WHERE owner = $group_id
```

Answer (score 0):

This feature is not available for groups like it is for personal profiles.

Here is a related to this question:
[How to get Facebook Group Albums via Open Graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13039878/how-to-get-facebook-group-albums-via-open-graph)

You may be able to resolve this by getting whitelisted as a Facebook Trusted Partner 
see: http://developers.facebook.com/preferredmarketingdevelopers/